# Flow assignment data type isn't compatible

Tags: visual-workflow, leads, lead-assignment

I create a schedule flow to verify if the daily events meets with some requirements, like enddate = TODAY and another value on a field (The first get records and the decision to verify if isn't null)

[image]

After this validations, I get the WhoId field on event: (First get records)

[image]

And I need to loop through them (the collection variable) because I wanna to assignment the WhoId field to update the status of the leads, but I can't do this, I create a collection of leads and it doesn't show the option to attribute the WhoId field.

[image]

And I made a loop through this collection variable, because I need the Ids of the WhoId field (Lead) to update them. But, when I tried to used the assignment property this wasn't possible, I received this message about incompatibility and I don't know how to solve this, I used the get records inside the loop to used the update records after, but I know that DML must not to be used inside loops.
How deal with this?
My goal is basically update the status of the leads (WhoId).

Comment: Instead of type Lead record. Did you try creating a variable of type String and all those Ids?

Comment: Yes! I was able to assign with a collection variable that is text, but then, I wasn't able to used to update the leads, I need to convert or something?

Comment: You may have to use get record element with Id in that variable and update it? Is it not working?

Comment: Yes, I tried this, I select the object lead and the id field but when I tried to select the variable that I used in the assignment it does not show

Comment: Are you using IN operator?

Comment: The IN solve the issue!! Thank you!! :)

Comment: I'm only receiving this message, is that something that could be solved too?
The “Events_End_Date_Today” Get Records element in this flow can cause performance issues. At run time, the flow starts an interview for each record specified in the Start element and stores each event in the $Record global variable. Check whether the “Events_End_Date_Today” element is still necessary, or add a filter so that the element accesses only the event in the $Record global variable.

Comment: I add the condition: Id = $record.Id, it's that right?

Comment: As this is scheduled flow you can query that in the start condition it self rather than adding getrecord element. This is just a warning as it is best practice. You can still activate and check it.

Comment: I wish I could but because I used a variable formula to get TODAY date it wasn't possible, but thank you!!!

Comment: yeah Got it. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of variable of type Record can you select variable of type String with collection variable so it stores the Ids of the WHOIDS.

To update the lead records you have to use Update record on Lead object where Id in the collection of Strings as below.

[image]

You can add the event object and condition in start condition only instead of get record element. It is just a warning as it may cause performance issue